# Tkinter timer not being able to detect ending

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a tkinter clock with a timer and I have almost got it done however I still cannot figure out how to detect when the timer is over.

I have tried something like this:

```
TimeOver = Label(root, text = Time Over)


def Update():
        if TimerVar < 0: #TimerVar is how much time is left
                TimeOver.pack()
        root.after(1000, Update)
Update()
```

However, that doesn't work. (I've just learned while true loops ruin it)
I've also tried this:

```
while True:
        if TimerVar < 0: #TimerVar is how much time is left
                TimerOver.pack()
```

And again that just stop's it from working.

My real code is:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
global CountDownTime
global TimerOn
CountDownTime = 0
TimerOn = False
root = Tk()
root.title("Alarm Clock")
root.geometry("500x500")
TimerVar = 0
Time = Label(root, text = f"{time}", font = ("Times New Roman", 50))
Time.place(x = "160", y = "100")
Timer = Label(root, text = f"{TimerVar}")
def TimerUpdate():
        global TimerVar
        TimerVar = TimerVar - 1
        Timer.config(text = f"{TimerVar}")
        root.after(1000, TimerUpdate)
def Update():
        global TimerOn
        global CountDownTime
        now = datetime.now()
        time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        Time.config(text = f"{time}")
        if TimerOn == True:
                root.after(1000, TimerUpdate)
        TimerOn = False
        root.after(1000, Update)

def AppendTime():
        global TimerVar
        TimerVar = TimerVar + 60
        Timer.config(text = f"{TimerVar}")

def DeductTime():
        global TimerVar
        TimerVar = TimerVar - 60
        Timer.config(text = f"{TimerVar}")
HigherTimer = Button(root, text = "+", command = AppendTime, font = ("Times New Roman", 25))
LowerTimer = Button(root, text = "-", command = DeductTime, font = ("Times New Roman", 25))

def Start():
        global TimerOn
        Timer.config(font = ("Times New Roman", 50))
        Timer.place(x = "160", y = "250")
        TimerOn = True
        CountDownTime = TimerVar * 1000
def CreateTimer():
        HigherTimer.pack()
        Timer.pack()
        LowerTimer.pack()
        StartTimer.pack()
        Time.place(x = "160", y = "150")

StartTimer = Button(root, text = "Start", command = Start, font = ("Times New Roman", 25))



createTimer = Button(root, text = "Set a timer", command = CreateTimer)
createTimer.pack()
Update()
root.mainloop()
#root.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this in your TimerUpdate() function:

```
def TimerUpdate():
    global TimerVar
    TimerVar = TimerVar - 1
    # Check to see if TimerVar has reached 0.
    if TimerVar <= 0:
        TimerVar = 0
        #  When it has reached 0, do something...
    Timer.config(text = f"{TimerVar}")
    root.after(1000, TimerUpdate)
```

The problem is that there was no for loop checking to see what the TimerVar was.